# C# Elegant method to derive DataRow subset using key column array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataRow: `Row[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`

I also have an array of primary key column names: `PKeys[1, 2, ...]`

I want an array or list which has an element for each PKeys element containing the value (string) from the matching elements in the DataRow.

Of course I could do this:

```
List<string> keyVals = new List<string>();
foreach (string PKey in PKeys)
{
    keyVals.Add(Row[PKey].ToString());
}
```

but is there a more elegant method, maybe with LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `Row` is `new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, ... }` or is it actually an n-dimesional array?

Comment: Row is an existing datarow as retrieved from a database, so can be treated as an n-dimensional array.

Comment: I think you'd have more luck treating it as an array of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PKeys.Select(key => Row[key].ToString()).ToList()
```

Comment: This one does it for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
keyVals.AddRange(from p in PKeys select Row[p].ToString());
```

Which is the same as

```
keyVals.AddRange(PKeys.Select(p => Row[p].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetKeyVals<T>(IEnumerable<T> rows, IEnumerable<T> pKeys)
{
    foreach (var PKey in PKeys)
    {
        yield return Row[PKey]; 
    }
}
```

So you could do this, using deferred execution.

```
var keysVals = GetKeyVals(Row, PKeys);
```

---

This is, in practice, the same as

```
var keysVals = PKeys.Select(pkey => return Row[pkey]);
```

I'm not sure I understand your rush to `IList<string>`.